# How to use material-ui breakpoint rule in external styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem adding a breakpoint rule to external styles for my component. In the documentation I found how to do it, but it is based on one file (component code + styles).

I have a table row component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { TableRow, TableCell } from "@material-ui/core";
import tablesCss from "./../styles/tables.css";

export const RowItem = withStyles(tablesCss)(
    ({ item, columns, classes }) => (
        <TableRow key={item[config.key]}>
            {columns.map(prop => (
                <TableCell
                    classes={{
                        root: classes.tableRow,
                    }}
                    key={prop}
                >
                    Lorem ipsum
                </TableCell>
            ))}
        </TableRow>
    )
);
```

and my external styles (tablesCss):

```
export default {
    tableRow: {
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
        },
    },
};
```

If I use `[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]` I get an error

> 'theme' is not defined

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that in order to use the theme, your styles need to be a function:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tableRow: {
    backgroundColor: "pink",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
    }
  }
});
export default styles;
```

When `withStyles` receives a function, it will pass the `theme` in as an argument to that function so that you can use the theme. The other change I would recommend would be to rename `tables.css` to `tablesCss.js`. The important aspect being that it is a JavaScript file not a CSS file. Depending on what bundling approach you are using and how it is configured, importing a CSS file would likely try to include that as CSS in the head of the HTML document and it is not valid CSS syntax -- it is JavaScript that is being leveraged to help generate CSS.

Here's a working example:

[image: Edit 5052ox9rmp]